# Nginx allow only specific API paths

Tags: nginx, restrictions

I am very new to Nginx and I have below configuration in Nginx

```
server {
location /api {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

So now suppose if user access `hostname/api/{{anything}}` should a**llow them to access**
but user tries to access `hostname/api/admin` it should deny them, So how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could specify the paths in the config like so : 
See relevant doc [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location)

```
 <Location /api/*>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
  <Location /api/admin>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
  </Location>
```

EDIT : Provided solution for apache, but nginx was required. [Location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) directive also exists in nginx :

```
location /api/* {
    allow all;
}

location /api/admin {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: I want it for Nginx and above is for Apache

Comment: Added the edit for nginx ;) Sorry about the misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks I am checking now !!

Comment: I have tested but it's not denying the request :( still I am able to /api/admin

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but try moving the deny location block for `/api/admin` above the allow location block for `/api/*`.